# Contar certos caracteres em uma palavra no python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um comando para ajudar na leitura de um globo terrestre.

```
entrada = int(input("Quantos centimetros no globo: "))
km = entrada * 425
m = km * 1000
cm = m * 100
print(entrada, "centimetros no globo equivalem a:", km, "quilometros", m, 
"metros e", cm, "centimetros.")
input()
```

Onde o comando transforma os centímetros do globo em números reais (Escala numérica). Mas muitas vezes, o M é um número meio grande e seria excelente transformar ele em notação cientifica. Supondo que sejam 20.000.000 m, é possível criar uma linha que "conte" quantos zeros tem no número e me retorne um valor, para então fazer a conversão?

Answer (score 6):

Basta você exibir o valor formatado utilizando o `e`.

```
>>> print('{:e}'.format(20000000))
2.000000e+07
```

Se você deseja limitar o número de casas decimais também, pode fazê-lo junto a formatação:

```
>>> print('{:.1e}'.format(20000000))
2.0e+07
```

Onde o `.1` indica a quantidade de casas decimais.

Vale lembrar que a notação `2.0e+07` é a notação científica aceita mundialmente e também vale lembrar que utiliza-se o ponto como separador decimal, não a vírgula, como utilizamos no Brasil.

Comment: Obrigado, foi extremamente útil!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o resto da divisão por 10 para saber quantos zeros a direita um número inteiro tem:

```
def conta_zeros(n):
  zeros = 0
  while n != 0 and n % 10 == 0: # se não for zero e ainda for divisível por 10
    zeros += 1 # mais um zero :D
    n /= 10 # tira um zero
  return zeros
```

Uma forma de fugir um pouco da matemática seria:

```
def conta_zeros(n):
  n = str(n) # converte o inteiro para string
  return len(n) - len(n.strip("0")) # retorna a quantidade de caracteres no inteiro original subtraído da quantidade de caracteres do inteiro sem os zeros a direita
```

Os resultados:

```
conta_zeros(1)           # retorna 0
conta_zeros(100)         # retorna 2
conta_zeros(3918237000)  # retorna 3
```

Pode implementar algo como:

```
n = 3187238000
zeros = conta_zeros(n)
base = str(n).strip("0") # retira os zeros sobrando
print(f"{n} = {base}*10^{zeros}") # imprime 3187238000 = 3187238*10^3
```

Se quer fazer isso para representar um número em notação científica, [veja essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263353/contar-certos-caracteres-em-uma-palavra-no-python/263356#answer-263369)

Comment: muito obrigado.